# Save entity and all its child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish-3

I'm having problems with updates of my MDFe entity, before explaining what happens, they looked like the image below, from it I can explain.

[image]

We can see that the MDFe has a ratio of one to many with this MDFeDocumento which also has a ratio of one to many with MDFeUnidadeTransporte and this has a ratio of one to many with MDFeUnidadeCarga.

The CRUD this structure is performed all over the MDFe. When editing a mdfe and to update the entity, the mdfeDocumento is changed, however, from there, the other entities do not suffer from the changes. For example, if when editing a MDFe and change the transport unit of a given document, while giving update on MDFe entity, the transport unit does not suffer modification.

How can I make these inserts / changes are made only saving the MDFe? If you can not insert / update only the parent entity, which is the best way to insert / update the other?

Thank you all, and if in doubt to comment on my explanation that I will improve.

Sorry for my bad English, I am Brazilian

The font code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mdfe")
public class MDFe implements IEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "modelo", nullable = false)
    private ModeloDocEnum modelo;
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Max(value = 999)
    @Column(name = "serie", nullable = false)
    private Integer serie;
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Column(name = "numero", nullable = false)
    private Long numero;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mdfe", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MDFeDocumento> mdfeDocumentos;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "mdfe_documentos")
public class MDFeDocumento implements IEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Size(max = 44)
    @Column(name = "chave", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String chave;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mdfe_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private MDFe mdfe;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mdfeDocumento", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MDFeUnidadeTransporte> unidadesTransporte;
}

public class MDFeUnidadeTransporte implements IEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "ident_unid_transp", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String identUnidTransp;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "tipo_unid_transp", nullable = false)
    private TipoUnidadeTransporteEnum tipoUnidTransp;
    @Min(0)
    @Column(name = "quantidade_rateada", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "decimal(15,2) default 0")
    private Double quantidadeRateada;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unidadeTransporte",
            orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<MDFeUnidadeCarga> unidadesCargas;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mdfe_documento_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MDFeDocumento mdfeDocumento;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "mdfe_unidades_cargas")
public class MDFeUnidadeCarga implements IEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "ident_unid_carga", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String identUnidCarga;
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "tipo_unid_carga", nullable = false)
    private TipoUnidadeCargaEnum tipoUnidCarga;
    @Min(0)
    @Column(name = "quantidade_rateada", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "decimal(15,2) default 0")
    private Double quantidadeRateada;
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "num_lacre", length = 60, nullable = false)
    @CollectionTable(name = "mdfe_lacres_cargas", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mdfe_cargas_id"))
    private List<String> lacres;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mdfe_unidade_transporte_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private MDFeUnidadeTransporte unidadeTransporte;
```

The update metod is:

```
@Override
public T update(T entity) {
    EntityManager em = this.getEntityManager();
    if (!em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    entity = em.merge(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return entity;
}
```

If I have time, I make an functional example to show you.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the cascade attribute in your @OneToMany tag, should be set to CascadeType.ALL, also you may need orphanRemoval = true
Post the relevant code and what you have tried.

Comment: Yes, I used the CascadeType.ALL, but didn't work, I try post the Entity code to show you

Comment: Mmm, seems that some fields are missing or omitted. For example, in MDFeDocumento there should be a MDFe `@ManyToOne` called mdfe, since it's being referenced by `mappedBy = "mdfe"` in MDFe. Also, you must maintain the relationship yourself, add the MDFe object to each MDFeDocumento's mdfe field since you are using `mappedBy = "mdfe"`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied and pasted wrong, I am editing and adding that code

Comment: I've just made a little test because I don't map collections as you do, but it worked for me in Jboss AS 7.1.0. Maybe it's a platform issue?
I've tried with one level of entities only (MDFe -> MDFeDocumento) but more levels (collections inside collections) shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ola. I use Glassfish, but my problem is just with more levels collections, If I was use only one collection (MDFe > MDFeDocumentos), work perfectly, but a lot of collections did not work. I think this problem is the Hibernate, but I can be wrong.

Comment: You tested there for me also works. The problem really is more entities. Thanks for your help. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I actually went ahead and added the MDFeUnidadeTransporte level and still worked for me... I'll add the last level and see if anything changes. Do you get an error? Are you sure the @ManyToOne side of the relationships are being populated before persisting?

Comment: Well, I tried again with all levels including `private List<String> lacres;`
It worked for me, maybe you can add your hibernate/glassfish versions and add the glassfish tag and see if somebody that uses it knows about some issue about this. Sorry I could not help.

Comment: My problem occurs when performing an update.
It does not make changes to the low entityes.

Comment: I do not have much time to test, but I will make an application to test that out of the main progeto.